# Using JSNLog with Angular 2 and .NET

Tags: angular, log4net, jsnlog

I'm trying to use jsnlog with Angular 2 but my project uses .Net.

Unfortunately, they for .NET Core, so can you help me to config jsnlog for .Net?

I get the following error when I start the app:

POST http://localhost:9000/jsnlog.logger 404 (Not Found)

Comment: 404 means there is nothing on the  http://localhost:9000/jsnlog.logger, you probably have a configuration error in your config. There should probably a handler listening there.

Comment: how do you config them? can you give me your web.config?

Comment: The [defaultAjaxUrl](http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/Configuration/OnServer/Jsnlog#defaultAjaxUrl) attribute in the config file might help you.

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of JSNLog.

Because you're seeing a 404, I suspect you didn't install the server side handler. Instruction on how to do that are in:
http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/DownloadInstall